# How do I install new SSL certificate on OSX using pyenv?

Tags: python, ssl, python-3.7, macos-catalina, pyenv

I keep running into the `SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED”` error when calling an API on python 3.7.3. Trying to solve [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835619/urllib-and-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-error) originally.

I'm using pyenv and I'm trying to run this command:

```
> cd "/Applications/Python 3.7.3/"
> sudo "./Install Certificates.command"
```

However, this path does not exist because I'm using `pyenv` and I can't seem to identify where python is actually installed how I actually run the `Install Certificates.command`

Any help would be great! Thanks

Comment: was this ever solved?